# how to update an array from input box in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, foreach

This is my code:

```
$uid=$_POST['uid'];
$fields = '';
if($uid==1){    
//having some error in this line
   foreach($query as $key => $value) {
    if ($i++ != 0) $fields .= ', '; 
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
      $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
      $fields .= "$key = $value";
      }
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE 2mcom SET $fields");
   }



  echo "<table>" ;
$result = mysql_query("select * from 2mcom where roll_no='138218600004'");
$i=1;

while (false != ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)))
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  //echo "$key: $value <br />";
  {
  echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "$key: ";
  echo "</td>";
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<input type="text" name="fld'.$i.'" value="'.$value.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="1"/>';
     $i++;
     echo "</td></tr>";
  }
  echo "<tr><td>";
   echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';

  echo "</tr></td>";
    echo'</form></table>';
```

I want to update this table 2mcom from the input text-box. Here i am fetching the field-name along with their values in input field from table "2mcom" using array.. now i want to update the field after editing.it is for result correction .

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: same as normal update.... because ur trying update text

Comment: @AmritaGupta try first.  try to code simple update

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database in newer versions of PHP (>5.5). Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: @Prashant: I have tried but its giving error for   $fld= $_POST["fld'.$i.'"]

Comment: @AmritaGupta you need to define your connection object first and then include that object when you are using certain MySQLi functions like `mysqli_query($link, $query);` or `mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $string);` its pretty straight forward, Read the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: @Edward: Update query in php for updating array? . Please see my question..

Comment: Do you want to update values in database one by one or all at the same time

Comment: This code is to select from the database, if you want to update the database you need an `UPDATE` query, if this sounds like what you need, write an update script, and, if you have problems, post it back here and we will be happy to help. To get you started: $query = "UPDATE `2mcom` (`col_1`, `col_2`) VALUES ('$val_1', $val_2') WHERE `roll_no` = '138218600004'";

Comment: @Edward: we are fetching field name dynamically so can't specify field name.  i have tried this:                                 $fld= $_POST["fld'.$i.'"];  /*giving error*/
$update= "update 2mcom set $key='$fld' where roll_no='138218600004'";

Comment: I have updated my previous code..please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give your text field a name, then you can do separate UPDATE queries to update each field individually.

UPDATE, consolidated version of previous code:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        $name = 'field';
        $id = $row['id']; //rename this with your row id, this will give you identifiable input names
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $key . ': ';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<form method="POST">';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'. $row['id'] .'"/>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="column[]" value="'. $key .'"/>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="field[]" value="'. $value .'"/>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

**UPDATE QUERY:**

```
function update_table($table, $col, $value, $id) {

    global $link; //mysqli object

    //escape values
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $value);
    $col = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $col);

    //update the database field
    $query = "UPDATE `$table` SET `$col` = '$value' WHERE `roll_id` = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    return true;

}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $col_count = count($_POST['column']);
    $field_count = count($_POST['field']);

    if($field_count == $col_count) {
    } else { 
        trigger_error("Col - Field mismatch", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['column']); $i++) {
        if(!update_table($table, $_POST['column'][$i], $_POST['field'][$i], $_POST['id'][$i])) {
            trigger_error("Error updating field", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

Try that.

Comment: `$row[$ref]` should be `$row[$ref[$i]]`

Comment: :i need a update query in php this code is giving error        Warning: Illegal offset type

Comment: Its printing only the 1st fieldname @Edward

Comment: $id = $row['id'];   its showing error as Undefined index: id  @Edward

Comment: @AmritaGupta I just spent my time writing this for you, you could at least read it! `//rename this with your row id, this will give you identifiable input names`

Comment: Thank you for the help. actually there is no field with name id thats why got confused. we are working with roll_no.

Comment: Ok, then use `roll_no` the answer has to be interpreted by you. :-)

Comment: Can we disable 3 or 4 input field(so that it can't be edited) in this code. @Edward

Comment: @AmritaGupta you can disable input fields in HTML with the `disabled='true'` attribute, you will need to create some logic in your PHP script to do this. Also, if you have any more question please consider opening a chat.

Comment: i have used if statement see my new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885381/how-to-make-some-dynamic-input-field-readonly-in-php